# Main camera not showing what my scene is looking like

Tags: unity-game-engine

Could anyone tell me why the Main Camera is not showing what my actual Scene is showing ?

Any problem in the hierarchy or ?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dgg5y.jpg)
Cheers

I tried to google my problem but didn't succeed to find any solution. For info I'm using a tile palette

Comment: Is your camera at the same Z position as your scene objects by any chance?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your camera's z is behind your tile pallette - you're looking behind it. Move the camera back.